# JavaFX on RPI (raspberry PI) freezes after system time change

Tags: javafx, raspberry-pi3, gluon

I have strange problem with JavaFX on RPI platform...
I am using raspberry PI RPI3B (latest Raspbian) with JavaFX 11.0.2 (JavaFX armv6hf SDK, Embedded armv6hf). I have found out that JavaFX application seems to be sensitive to system clock change. If I change system clock 10 seconds back, graphic of my application freezes for 10 seconds.
Any ideas what could be wrong and how to solve this problem?
I have tried also several examples from internet - the same problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is already an open bug filed on this issue: [Dependence on java.util.Timer freezes screen when OS time resets backwards](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8176499).